# DevServer Proxy Bypass POST Request Always Returns 404 Not Found

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

WebPack version `"version": "3.12.0"`
DevServer version `"version": "2.11.3"`

Code snippet below is how I configed my DevServer proxy. It is working for `GET` request which returns desired sample data however it does not work for `feedback` endpoint via `POST`. a `POST` request to `/feedback` always returns `404`. However, when I change the `method === 'POST'` to `GET` it will start work again.

I have confirmed the branch is reachable when sending a `POST` request to `/feedback` by throw an `Error('method: ${method}; url: ${url}')` inside the branch.

```
const proxyDummy = {
    '/': {
        bypass: (req) => {
            const { url, method } = req;

            if (method === 'GET') {
                switch (url) {
                    case '/data':
                        return SAMPLE_DATA.DATA; // JSON file path (Working)
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (method === 'POST') {
                switch (url) {
                    case '/feedback':
                        return SAMPLE_DATA.FEEDBACK; // JSON file path
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

Made another try with regular proxy routes config states in the doc,

```
const proxyDummy = {
    '/data': {
        target: generateURLFrom(SAMPLE_DATA.DATA),
        pathRewrite: { '^/data': '' }
    },
    '/feedback': {
        target: generateURLFrom(SAMPLE_DATA.FEEDBACK),
        pathRewrite: { '^/feedback': '' },
        bypass: (req, res, proxyOption) => {
            if (req.method !== 'POST') return false;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have not dig into the DevServer source code yet but I assume set up a proxy server using config code above does not just work for `GET` request, the proxy server underneath is `express` so config the proxy server like something below just work

```
const proxyDummy = {
    '/': {
        bypass: (req, res) => {
            const { url, method } = req;

            if (method === 'GET') {
                switch (url) {
                    case '/data':
                        return res.send('');
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (method === 'POST') {
                switch (url) {
                    case '/feedback':
                        return res.send();
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
};
```